# do query one table if exist else doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm working with SQL 2005, and have the following code:

```
DECLARE @exist4 INT
IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) existe
     FROM   sysobjects obj
     WHERE  obj.name = 'table4'
   ) > 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @exist4 = 1
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @exist4 = 0
    END

/*now if table4 exist i need add to my query but if i do something as it
i got next error
Invalid object name 'table4'.*/


IF ( @exist4 = 0 ) 
    BEGIN

        SELECT  [table].col1 ,
                [table].col2 ,
                [table].col3 ,
                [table].colN
        FROM    [table] ,
                table2 ,
                table3
        WHERE   [table].id = table1.id
                AND table3.id = table2.id
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  [table].col1 ,
                [table].col2 ,
                [table].col3 ,
                [table].colN
        FROM    [table] ,
                table2 ,
                table3 ,
                table4
        WHERE   [table].id = table2.id
                AND table3.id = table2.id
                AND table4.id = table3.id
    END
```

This code returns an error when Table4 does not exist.  How can I get this query to work?

Comment: What is the question?  The code seems to have the query.  By the way, you should be using proper JOIN syntax.  The comma is rather outdated.

Comment: that query work if the table exist, but if the tables doesn't exist it get a error

Comment: . . I edited your question so I think it is clearer. Review the edits to be sure I have the right explanation.

Comment: What is the error it is returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that table4 does not exist at the time the query is parsed. That means you can't run the query.

What you need to do is to delay the parsing of that part of the query until you know that table4 exists.

You can do this by putting the query in a string then running the stored procedure sp_excutesql. Something like this:

```
 DECLARE @myQueryString NVARCHAR(4000);
 SET @myQueryString = N'select table.col1, table.col2, table.col3, table.colN into #tmp
     from table,table2,table3,table4
     where table.id=table2.table1id 
     and table3.table2id=table2.id
     and table4.table3id=table3id';
 EXEC sp_executesql @myQueryString;
```

The part of the query that references table4 is only available as a string when the whole query is parsed the first time, so the parser sees just a string, not the reference to the various tables. When you run sp_executesql the string is then parsed and run. And since you put this inside your IF block it will only parse and run when it knows that table4 exists.

Comment: That will create `#tmp` then drop it immediately as soon as the batch ends. In fact a missing object isn't a problem as long as the statement isn't executed anyway. It will be subject to deferred compile. e.g. `IF 1 = 0 SELECT * FROM DOESNOTEXIST ELSE SELECT * FROM sys.objects` runs fine.

Comment: thanks but i dont have the sp called sp_executesql i have done exec (@statment) it runs

Comment: @angel - You do have `sp_executesql` but you need to use `EXEC sp_executesql`. The `EXEC` part is only optional for the first statement in a batch. This won't help you though because as soon as the statement executes and the child scope exits it will drop the temp table it creates via `SELECT ... INTO`.

Comment: Yes, a global temp table will be required (##tmp) in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer might be trying to evaluate the select statement syntax, so wrap that in an sp_executesql statement to delay that. Try:

```
    IF ( SELECT OBJECT_ID('SQLInstances')
   ) IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3, table1.colN into #tmp from table1,table2,table3
where table1.id=table2.table1id 
and table3.table2id=table2.id'
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3, table1.colN into #tmp from table1,table2,table3,table4
where table1.id=table2.table1id 
and table3.table2id=table2.id
and table4.table3id=table3id'
    END
```